# Prove that there are no convex functions on compact manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis, compact-manifolds

This one seems intuitively obvious to me but I don't know how to prove it.  Suppose you have a compact manifold $M$ with a function $f$ defined on it.  Given two points $x$ and $y$ on the manifold, let $\gamma_{xy}: [0,1]\rightarrow M$ be the geodesic between $x$ and $y$.  Then we say a function is convex if, $\forall x, y\in M, \lambda \in [0,1],\,\,\,\, f(\gamma_{xy}(\lambda)) \le (1-\lambda)f(x) + \lambda f(y)$

I can't think of any function on a compact manifold for which this is actually true, and I suspect that there are no convex functions on compact manifolds.  Can anyone point me to the relevant proof?

Comment: It's hard to attain maximum when you are convex.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Every non-constant smooth function on a compact manifold has two critical points.

Comment: What about continuous but non-smooth functions?

Comment: @DavidPfau Without smoothness, argue as follows: let $s=\max_M f$ and $N=f^{-1}(s)$. On one hand, $N$ is closed. On another hand, every geodesic passing through a point of $N$ must be contained in $N$. Hence $N$ is also open.

Answer (score 1):

In this paper

*Yau, Shing-Tung*, [**Non-existence of continuous convex functions on certain Riemannian manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01351342), Math. Ann. 207, 269-270 (1974). [ZBL0261.53036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0261.53036). S.T. Yau proved that there does not exists any non-trivial continuous convex function on complete Riemannian manifold with finite volume. Since any compact set has finite volume so all convex function is trivial.